# PHP include not loading file

Tags: php, apache, server, include, require

Im runninng lamp stack locally on my ubuntu 16.04 OS and Im getting problems when including files. My code in index.php:
`<?php include('steamauth/steamauth.php'); ?>
<?php include('steamauth/userinfo.php');?>`

my structure is:

`index.php
steamauth
    steamauth.php
    userinfo.php`
Im getting the following error:
include(steamauth/userinfo.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/html/index.php
include(): Failed opening 'steamauth/userinfo.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /var/www/html/index.php
I tried using the full path , adding webroot before the path , changing include_path in php.ini , but nothing seemed to work . what do i do ?

Comment: To test that there isn't a problem with your include, can you try putting the include files in the same folder as the index.php and change the includes to 'steamauth.php' and 'userinfo.php'? Let me know if that works?

Comment: If that works, put the files back in steamauth and change your includes to "{$_SERVER[DOCUMENT_ROOT]}/steamauth/steamauth.php" and "{$_SERVER[DOCUMENT_ROOT]}/steamauth/userinfo.php". NOTE: You must change the single quotes to double quotes to test this. Let me know if that works.

Comment: Next, create a test file "index.php" in the steamauth folder and simply put "<?php print "hello"; ?> in it. Then try and load [your domain]/steamauth/index.php in your browser. Does the page load?

Comment: This also seems to be a duplicate of your question 2 days ago (with a few minor changes). Next time you should add more details to your existing question rather than creating the question again.

Comment: the thing is i have 1 more file that i didnt mention called navbar.php and i can include it no problem. i can even access the index.php in steamauth folder that you wrote about . But i can not include those 2 files : userinfo.php and steamauth.php although they have the same permissions as the other files. Any ideas ?

Comment: Could it be some problem with the code in these files ?

Comment: Can you move the files into the same folder as the index.php and changing the includes to  'steamauth.php' and 'userinfo.php'? Does that work?

Comment: (It's not the code in those files BTW).

Comment: i did that and it did not work. i get this error:  include(userinfo.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/html/index.php on line 3

Comment: Are you able to post the contents of your index.php file and your userinfo.php file?

Comment: Also, where is your "navbar.php" file? Is that also in the steamauth folder?

Comment: i will edit the post in a minute

Comment: no , currently all files are in /var/www/html

Comment: Put the navbar.php file in the steamauth folder and try to include it from there. Does that work?

Comment: I am guessing that you are having problems editing your post, as your code snippets make no sense at the moment.

Comment: accessing navbar.php when it is in the steamauth folder didnt work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Check folder pemission**

Check that the Apache user has access to the include folder.

**Check file permissions**

Check that the permissions on the files that you are including can be read and executed by the Apache user.

**Check PHP settings**

It could be caused by one of the following PHP settings:

open_basedir:
If this is set PHP won't be able to access any file outside of the specified directory (not even through a symbolic link).

safe mode:
If this is turned on restrictions might apply.

**Make path absolute**

Check that $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] is correctly set for your domain by using:

```
print $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]; // Add to top of you index.php file.
```

Then change your includes to:

```
$_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . '/sub_folder/file_to_include';
```

**Check for typos and spelling mistakes**

Carefully check that what you think you have called the folder and what you are using to include it are spelt the same.

BTW: You can just use the following in your index.php file:

```
<?php
include('steamauth/steamauth.php');
include('steamauth/userinfo.php');
```

You also don't need to add the closing ?> at the end of the file - it's actually good practice not to.

Comment: i set them to 777 before. my permissions:  drwxrwxrwx 2 www-data www-data 4096 окт 28 00:35 steamauth

Comment: i can access navbar.php when it is in the steamauth directory

Comment: Check file permissions of the include files can be read and executed by the Apache user.

Comment: i did all and the navbar.php file keeps loading with all the methods mentioned above , but the other 2 which are in the same directory dont and it gives me error: include(/var/www/html/userinfo.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/html/index.php

Comment: Can you send the output of "ls -al" from the folder that all the files are now in?

Comment: -rwxrwxr-x 1 misho    misho    1569 окт 28 00:35 navbar.php  
-rwxrwxrwx 1 www-data www-data 1835 окт 27 11:50 steamauth.php  
-rwxrwxrwx 1 www-data www-data 2510 окт 27 11:50 userInfo.php

Comment: Your "userinfo.php" file appears to be called "userInfo.php". Linux is case sensitive.

Comment: Bro , i feel very stupid searching for some complex solutions online without ever realizing something so simple. Everytime i checked for typos i did not notice the difference between I and i . good thing there is some kind guy to point me to my simple but not that easy(atleast for me it seems) to find mistake. Thank you for the time you spent . I appreciate it. ;)

Comment: Anytime :) We are all new to PHP and Linux at some point. My answer did include "Check for typos and spelling mistakes", I'd appreciate an upvote on the answer. Thanks.

Comment: Ofcourse, i upvoted it. It said that it will show up once i get 15 reputation.

Comment: BTW. I used to run teams of devs and I was the guy that they would call over when they could not see what was causing issues like this. Even experienced devs can spend a long time looking for mistakes like this, so don't feel too bad about it. Just try to remember to check for this if you ever see this type of problem again. You learn much more from your mistakes!